# I need this formula to include blank cells within the range_length as well

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

```
=ArrayFormula(transpose(split(concatenate(rept(A:A&char(9),(len(B:B)-len( substitute(B:B,",",))+1))),char(9))))
```

This is working good but the only change needed is to let it not to skip blank cells in between

[SEE IMAGE ONCE FOR CLEARER VIEW ON WHAT IS NEEDED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNNL6.png)

[SAMPLE SHEET](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PoLgj_ElxiEgK3hsU-Ixi1AWfgbD2cPAxzUUAhMsDgY/edit#gid=2138211595)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(transpose(split(concatenate(rept(A2:A&char(9)&",",if(isBlank(B2:B)=false,(len(Q6:Q)-len( substitute(B6:B,",",))+1),0))),",")))
```

The same has been split into multiple lines below for readability

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
             transpose(
             split(
             concatenate(
             rept(A6:A&char(9)&",",if(isBlank(B2:B)=false,
                                     (len(B6:B)-len(substitute(B6:B,",",))+1),0)
             )
             ),",")
             )
             )
```

I just add char(9) as a way to ensure a blank cell is added when the split comma.

The if statements check to see if there is any empty row in column B and skips it else blank rows in column B will also create more rows. This will create an error when the number of row output exceeds the number of rows available.

Comment: I tried using this. Its throwing me an error : "Function REPT parameter 2 value is -26. It should be greater than or equal to 0."

Comment: The code works for the example data you showed in the sheet. IF share a test case where it fails, i might be able to improve the code

Comment: Can you check it up here plz : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PoLgj_ElxiEgK3hsU-Ixi1AWfgbD2cPAxzUUAhMsDgY/edit#gid=2138211595 Its has weird results when there is singe string in cell. In the above example, 26/05/2017 is missing

Comment: It is fixed now, I will edit the answer to match. If this solves your question please accept the answer.